# Blazor Foreach only renders last color

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-core, blazor

I have searched everywhere and cant find an answer so any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have a ForEach loop on a razor page and it loops through a list of appointments each one has a different color (I watched the whole process in the debugger and the values.) but it only renders all of the looped items as the last color in the foreach loop.

Here is the loop

```
@foreach (var a in appt.ToList())
{
   <ApptCard @key="a.Text" Text="@a.Text" BoxColor="@users.Where(x => x.Id == a.Id).FirstOrDefault().Color"/>
}
```

Here is the Card that is being looped

```
@using System.Drawing

<style>
    .apptColor{
        background-color: @rgbaColor;
    }
</style>

<MudPaper Class="pa-2 apptColor">@($"{Text})</MudPaper>

@code {
    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; } = null!;
    [Parameter] public string BoxColor { get; set; } = null!;
    private string rgbaColor;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
            var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(BoxColor);
            int r = Convert.ToInt16(color.R);
            int g = Convert.ToInt16(color.G);
            int b = Convert.ToInt16(color.B);
            rgbaColor = string.Format("rgba({0}, {1}, {2}, {3});", r, g, b, .2);

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

the colors come from the database.

[what's rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IVxx.png)

In the picture the first one should be red, second brown, third green, and the fourth red.

Comment: If this is a direct copy-paste: you're missing a closing " here: <MudPaper Class="pa-2 apptColor">@($"{Text})</MudPaper>
Should be <MudPaper Class="pa-2 apptColor">@($"{Text}")</MudPaper>

Answer (score 0):

You could try use Guid to make each instance of component unique.
ApptCard.razor

```
@using System.Drawing

<MudPaper id="@Uid" Class="pa-2 apptColor">@Text</MudPaper>

<style>
    @css{
        background-color: @rgbaColor;
    }
</style>

@code {
    private string Uid { get; set; } =$"xx-{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}";
    private string css => $"#{Uid}.apptColor";

    [Parameter] public string Text { get; set; } = null!;
    [Parameter] public string BoxColor { get; set; } = null!;
    private string rgbaColor;
    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        var color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(BoxColor);
        int r = Convert.ToInt16(color.R);
        int g = Convert.ToInt16(color.G);
        int b = Convert.ToInt16(color.B);
        rgbaColor = string.Format("rgba({0}, {1}, {2}, {3});", r, g, b, .2);

        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }
}
```

Home.razor

```
@page "/"

@{
    var appt = new List<string> { "Blue", "Red", "Yellow" };
}
@foreach (var a in appt.ToList())
{
    <AptCard BoxColor="@a" Text="@a"></AptCard>
}
```

Test result
[image]